# Image aespect ratio - max-width is required in Chrome but breaks mobile Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have flexbox columns which contain images. The images have a max-width of 100% and need to maintain their aspect ratio.

I have a really strange bug that I'm not able to recreate outside of site. I'm afraid I cant share this so the code example is an approximation only.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575014774591-d036b92ae5ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=612&q=80" height="912" width="1462" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575014774591-d036b92ae5ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=612&q=80" height="912" width="1462" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575014774591-d036b92ae5ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=612&q=80" height="912" width="1462" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575014774591-d036b92ae5ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=612&q=80" height="912" width="1462" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575014774591-d036b92ae5ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=612&q=80" height="912" width="1462" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575014774591-d036b92ae5ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=612&q=80" height="912" width="1462" />
  </li>
</ul>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li {
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jms4vyk0/1/

In Chrome if I remove the `height: auto;` from the image then the aspect ratio breaks. However in iOS Safari the aspect radio works without `height: auto;` but breaks when I add it. In desktop Safari it's broken either way.

Comment: try to remove the width/height attribute

Comment: I believe this will cause the page to resize once the images load so would be bad for UX

Comment: In all of the cases the page will resize since you are changing the width/height using CSS

Comment: But they CSS is applied immediately while the images have to load and the sizes wouldn't be known untill this had completed.

Comment: If you have fixed height and custom width, why you don't add the images as a background-image? (in style) you will get a lot control.